# When working with an explicit cursor, the error

Tags: oracle

```
declare
cursor cur_emploc is
                    select CRN,
                           ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2
                      from DCO_LOADING_ATTRIBUTES;
some_crn cur_emploc%ROWTYPE;
TYPE c_crn IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
l_crn_tab c_crn;
begin 

select CRN BULK COLLECT INTO l_crn_tab from tableau.T_DCO_CRN_FINAL_3;

OPEN cur_emploc;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_emploc INTO some_crn;
        EXIT WHEN cur_emploc%NOTFOUND;
        IF some_crn.CRN is not null then
           IF l_crn_tab.EXISTS (some_crn.CRN) THEN
              dbms_output.put_line(some_crn.CRN);
            
         else l_error_not_search_srn:=l_error_not_search_srn||','||some_crn.CRN;  
           END IF;
        ELSE 
           insert into ... 
        END IF;
   END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_emploc;


EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line( SQLCODE||chr(13)||chr(10)||DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);
END;
```

in row "IF l_crn_tab.EXISTS (some_crn.CRN) THEN"
erorr ORA-06502:character to number conversion error number or value error

table DCO_LOADING_ATTRIBUTES.CRN data is there :
CR00000
CR000001

What could be the reason ? And is it correct to fill the collection and check this collection element during fetch?

Comment: English, please!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in English

Comment: Is there anything else but ORA-06512? Should be, so - please, post the whole error stack.

Comment: @Littlefoot   procedure successfully completed. Im on option 'SET DEFINE off'. I can only show an error DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace.

Comment: Or, simpler, remove that EXCEPTION as it does nothing *smart* at all. Let Oracle raise the error, then post error stack (not as a comment - edit the question).

Comment: @Littlefoot ORA-06512: на  line 18
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).

Comment: @Littlefoot IF l_crn_tab.EXISTS (some_crn.CRN) THEN. There eror

Comment: @Littlefoot i got another problem with this script. In some_crn.CRN there null. 
The branch operator was supposed to process the cursor line on the line "ELSE  INSERT INTO", but he moved in row "ELSE l_error_not_search_srn". If operator buggy or 
I wrote incorrectly ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'EXISTS' IS NOT FOR CHECKING THE PRESENCE OF THE CHECKED VALUE IN THE COLLECTION.
for this purpose 'member of'

```
 declare
    cursor cur_emploc is
                        select CRN,
                               ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2
                          from DCO_LOADING_ATTRIBUTES;
    some_crn cur_emploc%ROWTYPE;
    TYPE c_crn IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    l_crn_tab c_crn;
    begin 
    
    select CRN BULK COLLECT INTO l_crn_tab from tableau.T_DCO_CRN_FINAL_3;
    
    OPEN cur_emploc;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur_emploc INTO some_crn;
            EXIT WHEN cur_emploc%NOTFOUND;
            IF some_crn.CRN is not null then
               IF some_crn.CRN member of l_crn_tab  THEN
                  dbms_output.put_line(some_crn.CRN);
                
               
               END IF;
            ELSE 
               dbms_output.put_line('ничего нету'); 
            END IF;
       END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_emploc;
    
    
    --EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --dbms_output.put_line( SQLCODE||chr(13)||chr(10)||DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);
    END;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, this is the error line:

```
IF l_crn_tab.EXISTS (some_crn.CRN)             --> some_crn.crn = CR00000
```

`exists` method checks whether element (passed to it) exists, but element as a NUMBER (first element, second, fiftieth, ...).

> EXISTS(n) returns TRUE if the nth element in a collection exists. Otherwise, EXISTS(n) returns FALSE. Mainly, you use EXISTS with DELETE to maintain sparse nested tables. You can also use EXISTS to avoid raising an exception when you reference a nonexistent element. When passed an out-of-range subscript, EXISTS returns FALSE instead of raising SUBSCRIPT_OUTSIDE_LIMIT.

You're passing a string, e.g. CR00000. Oracle is unable to implicitly convert it to a number, so it raises an error.

Now, the question is what are you really checking here, so solution depends on it.

Comment: thanks answer.  I did not understand the description of the method 'Exists', method search index in collection, i need value  in collection.

Answer (score 1):

> in row "IF l_crn_tab.EXISTS (some_crn.CRN) THEN" erorr ORA-06502:character to number conversion error number or value error

[exists](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99968)(n), where n -- index of element as integer.